# Unable to create AWS CodeBuild Webhook

Tags: amazon-web-services, webhooks, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to create a webhook via AWS CodeBuild and this is the error I receive.

[image: This is the error]
I've also tried creating the webhook via AWS CLI using the following command:

```
aws codebuild create-webhook --project-name myClassifiedProjectName
```

And I get the same error:

```
An error occurred (OAuthProviderException) when calling the CreateWebhook operation: Unable to create webhook at this time. Please try again later.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The same thing is has been going on for about 24 hours.  I guess I just have to wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it was a server error on AWS' side. I tried again 4 hours later and it's suddenly working now.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into the same problem and was able to resolve it by getting proper permissions for my Github user. Basically my Github user did not have access to create a webhook, though I had permission to read the repo.

Comment: This was also the issue for me. The Github user you're using to authorize CodeBuild must be made an administrator of the project in order to create the webhook. I think the administrator access can be revoked afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

For other people coming here looking for a solution: For us, it was about the 20 webhook limit per a GitHub repo. We have a monorepo and currently have a trigger for each projects pipeline, which obviously doesn't work out anymore. Obviously a more helpful error message would've saved several hours of debugging...

Answer (score 1):

We use [Bitbucket IP whitelisting](https://bitbucket.org/blog/big-strides-cloud-security-ip-whitelisting-required-2-step-verification-bitbucket), and despite adding the relevant [AWS ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html), I also could not create a web hook. I resorted to disabling IP whitelisting, setting up the CodeBuild again, then re-enabling it.

**Note**: Bitbucket will notify all admins that the whitelist has been disabled!

Answer (score 1):

To add my solution (way after the fact), I fixed this problem by selecting **Enable SSO** on my GitHub personal Access token. If your GitHub organisation uses SSO, and you want CodeBuild to be able to access a private repo in your organisation, then you will need to allow SSO on the personal access token.